# How to clone and change id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I need to clone the id and then add a number after it like so `id1`, `id2`, etc. Every time you hit clone you put the clone after the latest number of the id.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#id").clone().after("#id");
});
```

Answer (score 233, accepted):

```js
$('#cloneDiv').click(function(){


  // get the last DIV which ID starts with ^= "klon"
  var $div = $('div[id^="klon"]:last');

  // Read the Number from that DIV's ID (i.e: 3 from "klon3")
  // And increment that number by 1
  var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;

  // Clone it and assign the new ID (i.e: from num 4 to ID "klon4")
  var $klon = $div.clone().prop('id', 'klon'+num );

  // Finally insert $klon wherever you want
  $div.after( $klon.text('klon'+num) );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<button id="cloneDiv">CLICK TO CLONE</button> 

<div id="klon1">klon1</div>
<div id="klon2">klon2</div>
```

---

### Scrambled elements, retrieve highest ID

Say you have many elements with IDs like `klon--5` but scrambled (not in order). Here we **cannot** go for `:last` or `:first`, therefore we need a mechanism to retrieve the highest ID:

```js
const all = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="klon--"]');
const maxID = Math.max.apply(Math, [...all].map(el => +el.id.match(/\d+$/g)[0]));
const nextId = maxID + 1;

console.log(`New ID is: ${nextId}`);
```

```html
<div id="klon--12">12</div>
<div id="klon--34">34</div>
<div id="klon--8">8</div>
```

Comment: is it also possible to have a button inside the div that removes the current id div?

Comment: @user1324780 Yes it is possible, but you should post that as a new question. Anyways the clue is to find the `.closest(div[id^=id])` and `.remove` that div.

Comment: How to use this with $(this)??
It is not work $(this).('div[id^="picker-time-start"]');

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan your answer does not contribute anything

Comment: @user3058963. Comment sections are not meant to contribute to, or discuss unrelated specific problems. Said that, might be you're missing `.find()` or might be something completely different. If you have a problem please do a research, and Ask a New Question. And please take a [tour] to better understand how this pages work.

Answer (score 49):

**Update:** As [Roko C.Bulijan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10127093/297641) pointed out.. you need to use .insertAfter to insert it after the selected div. Also see updated  code if you want it appended to the end instead of beginning when cloned multiple times. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HGtmR/4/)

**Code:**

```
   var cloneCount = 1;;
   $("button").click(function(){
      $('#id')
          .clone()
          .attr('id', 'id'+ cloneCount++)
          .insertAfter('[id^=id]:last') 
           //            ^-- Use '#id' if you want to insert the cloned 
           //                element in the beginning
          .text('Cloned ' + (cloneCount-1)); //<--For DEMO
   });
```

---

Try,

```
$("#id").clone().attr('id', 'id1').after("#id");
```

If you want a automatic counter, then see below,

```
   var cloneCount = 1;
   $("button").click(function(){
      $("#id").clone().attr('id', 'id'+ cloneCount++).insertAfter("#id");
   });
```

Comment: You missed a great opportunity to use `'id'+ ++ id` in your code.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You are right, but the question was how to change the attr of the cloned element and so I missed to notice the `.after`. See updated answer.

Comment: :) +1 to round it to 5 ! ;) nice use of `[id^=id]:last` Congrats.

Comment: can this be applied to names as well?

Answer (score 8):

This is the simplest solution working for me.

```
$('#your_modal_id').clone().prop("id", "new_modal_id").appendTo("target_container");
```

Answer (score 4):

This works too

```js
 var i = 1;
 $('button').click(function() {
     $('#red').clone().appendTo('#test').prop('id', 'red' + i);
     i++; 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <button>Clone</button>
  <div class="red" id="red">
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .red {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have created a generalised solution. The function below will change ids and names of cloned object. In most cases, you will need the row number so Just add "data-row-id" attribute to the object.

```
function renameCloneIdsAndNames( objClone ) {

    if( !objClone.attr( 'data-row-id' ) ) {
        console.error( 'Cloned object must have \'data-row-id\' attribute.' );
    }

    if( objClone.attr( 'id' ) ) {
        objClone.attr( 'id', objClone.attr( 'id' ).replace( /\d+$/, function( strId ) { return parseInt( strId ) + 1; } ) );
    }

    objClone.attr( 'data-row-id', objClone.attr( 'data-row-id' ).replace( /\d+$/, function( strId ) { return parseInt( strId ) + 1; } ) );

    objClone.find( '[id]' ).each( function() {

        var strNewId = $( this ).attr( 'id' ).replace( /\d+$/, function( strId ) { return parseInt( strId ) + 1; } );

        $( this ).attr( 'id', strNewId );

        if( $( this ).attr( 'name' ) ) {
            var strNewName  = $( this ).attr( 'name' ).replace( /\[\d+\]/g, function( strName ) {
                strName = strName.replace( /[\[\]']+/g, '' );
                var intNumber = parseInt( strName ) + 1;
                return '[' + intNumber + ']'
            } );
            $( this ).attr( 'name', strNewName );
        }
    });

    return objClone;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#cloneDiv').click(function(){


  // get the last DIV which ID starts with ^= "klon"
  var $div = $('div[id^="klon"]:last');

  // Read the Number from that DIV's ID (i.e: 3 from "klon3")
  // And increment that number by 1
  var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;

  // Clone it and assign the new ID (i.e: from num 4 to ID "klon4")
  var $klon = $div.clone().prop('id', 'klon'+num );

  // Finally insert $klon wherever you want
  $div.after( $klon.text('klon'+num) );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```