# Dynamically adding extra row into jquery accordion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery

I would like to have some question how to control accordion dynamically.

when click add button I supposed to add one more row sub accordion and 
click remove button will remove last row of accordion.

then I have a question how to control this.

My source code as below.

JS :

```
$("#addResolution").click(function (e) {
    alert("Add new resolution. ");
});

$("#removeResolution").click(function (e) {
    alert("Remove new resolution. ");
});


                <h3><a href="#" class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Resolution)
                </a></h3>
                <div>
                    <button class="ui-button ui-button-text-only ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="addResolution">
                        <span class="ui-button-text">ADD</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="ui-button ui-button-text-only ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="removeResolution">
                        <span class="ui-button-text">DEL</span>
                    </button>
                    <div id="accordionSub">
                        <h3><a href="#" class="editor-label">
                             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Resolution)
                        </a></h3>
                        <div class="editor-field">    
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Resolution,
                            new
                            {
                                style = "width:" + 100 + "%; height:" + 5 + "em;"
                            }) 
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Resolution)

                            <br />
                            <label id="lblFileUploadResolution">Choose Image File</label>
                            <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="fileToUploadResolution" style="width:89%;" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp" />
                            <input type="button" id="btnFileUploadResolution" value="Upload" style="width:10%;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

When I click Add button dynamically add one more column and increase accordion sub id (example : accordian1, accordian2, accordian3)

and click remove button then delete last row.

Please help me thank you !

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Sorry I don't have point to put image yet. I just want click Add or Remove button and add more accordion like div id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it seems from your comment on the previous answer that you're having trouble with the code that's generated by razor, like:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Resolution)
```

Obviously, because that code is server side, you need a client side solution.

One option is to use jquery clone to clone the element, give the clone a unique id and then append it ... [see here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10127093/637617)

so you would do something like:

```
var clone = $('#accordionSub').clone();
clone.attr('id', 'id1').insertAfter($('#accordionSub'));
```

This is totally untested but hopefully will point you in the right direction. I've hard coded the new id as 'id1', but obviously you'll need to work out what the id of the new element should be.

Comment: Hi , Thank you so much for your answer, u understand exactly my point, It's MVC model. I will try to handle model side after finish view side. I already follow what u guided. and after I click add button it's will generate more accordion. however, there is no content inside(even thought click accordion, nothing happen) do you have any idea about this? thank you !

Comment: looks like disable .. if I open accordion for original and click add then it's same clone open but I cannot do anything like disable

Comment: @clear.choi - I'm not totally sure what you mean ... maybe if you try and explain again I can understand better.

Comment: Oh so sorry , I already copy and it's already show added item. However, that copied item cannot do anything looks like disable. Originally if I click accordion it's extend and show message and some event that define in MODEL section, however copied item don't do any action..

Comment: and if I make like this -->  alert("Add new resolution. ");
                    var clone = $('#accordionSub').clone(true);

                    //clone.attr('id', 'accordionSub1').insertAfter($('#accordionSub'));

                    clone.attr('id', 'accordionSub1');
                    clone.appendTo("#accordionSub");  ---> it's work and extend copied accordion but inside of element it's look like disable I cannot edit and do for some event.

Comment: It's very difficult without seeing what you mean I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
$('#addAccordion').click( function() {
    var newDiv = "<div><h3>Q2 New Question</h3><div>New Content</div></div>";
    $('#accordionSub').append(newDiv)
    $('#accordionSub').accordion("refresh");        
});
```

Comment: but I need to put <div id="accordionSub">
                        <h3><a href="#" class="editor-label">
                             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Resolution) like this but it's error do you know how do I put into the newDiv with @ Thank you !