# How to dynamically add the content in jsp page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

MyServlet forwards to Mypage.jsp as

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages_homepage.jsp?value="+count).forward(request, response);
```

where count is an integer value generated

Below is my JSP code(Mypage.jsp),

```
<body  onload="getPage('<%request.getParameter("value");%>')">
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

Below is my javascript code,

```
function getPage(match){
    var arr = new Array();
    var ele = document.getElementById('app');
    for(var i=0;i<match;i++){
        var newdiv = document.createElement("label");
        newdiv.id = arr[i];
        newdiv.value="Page";
        ele.appendChild(newdiv);
    }
}
```

What I want is that, I want 'Page' to be displayed 'match' number of times. But I'm not being able to do so by the above code. Their might be something wrong with my js code. Can anyone suggest me any corrections?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `arr` ? what should it contain? Interesting your nomenclatures, you named a var `newdiv` that actually is a `<LABEL>` element and you're trying to add a `value` attribute to a `label` element and an `ID` from an empty array.... Can you please enlighten us?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I was trying something to give an unique id to newdiv, but I know I have have written a messed up code. Can you suggest anything for it?

Comment: you mean something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126395/how-to-jquery-clone-and-change-id ?

Comment: What is returned by `<%request.getParameter("value");%>`? Can you please preformulate your question and make it more clear about what you actually want?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan <%request.getParameter("value");%> this returns a number.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I just updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for their help but I think I got the answer,

Instead of

```
<body  onload="getPage('<%request.getParameter("value");%>')">
```

I wrote,

```
<body onload="getPage('<%=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("value"))%>')">
```

But thanks everyone again for their useful pointers.

Answer (score 4):

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AzUvEfU/1/edit)***

Taking in consideration that your page has something like:

```
<body  onload="getPage(5)">
```

```
function getPage(n) {

   var ele = $('#app');
   var labels = ""; // An empty string will be populated with labels elements:
   for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
       labels += '<label id="'+ i +'"> Page </label>'
   }
   ele.append( labels ); // append only once outside the loop!

}
```

The result will be:

```
 <label id="0"></label>
 <label id="1"></label>
 <label id="2"></label>
 <label id="3"></label>
 <label id="4"></label>
```

If you want to start from `1` instead of `0` use:

```
labels += '<label id="'+ (i+1) +'"> Page </label>'
```

<sub>**Note:** `ID` starting with (/ containing only) a number - is only valid in HTML5</sub>

Comment: yep your demo works perfectly fine, but the only thing is that I want to dynamically send a value to the function 'getPage(num)'. I have updated my question

Comment: IDs should start with a letter in HTML. Should probably add a prefix to the number.

Comment: @TiiJ7 I was about to write that *ID starting with a number* and *containing only a number* is **perfectly valid** in **HTML5**.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I looked it up and you are correct. My bad then :) Ref: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/datatypes.html#common.data.id

Comment: @SaumilSoni you want to dynamically send a value... you did not stated that inside your question (or I don't understand JSP) but instead you showed us you use  a  body `onload` handler... Than don't use the onload :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I apologize for that, but now that you know can you tell me how to pass the value dynamically?

Comment: @SaumilSoni dynamically ... on what event? You mean you have a timer that's calling your function? You can try to use `.html()` instead of `.append()` to make sure the old stuff is cleared before adding new things. And call your function `getPage()` inside that dynamic whatever of yours.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm planning to call my function through onload event within body tag

Comment: @SaumilSoni Sorry, but... What's the issue you're encountering?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sorry for not expressing myself clearly. What I'm trying to do here is generate value 'count' in a servlet and transfer the value of 'count' by writing request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages_homepage.jsp? value="+count).forward(request, response);  So within my jsp page I could get the value of count by writing request.getParameter("value"). Now I want to pass this value to my function as getPage('<%request.getParameter("value")%>'). Now I want to call the function by onload event. Now within the function I want to execute the 'for' loop 'match' number of times

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan hey man thanks for your help, I have just posted an answer to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code is working and i have tested it

Since you don't have any content in the label tag hence it is not visible in browser

Secondly a small error
 in 6th line of js code

```
       newdiv.id = arr[i];
```

arr[i] is not  given any value hence change it with

```
        newdiv.id = i;
```

enjoy your code

Comment: this has already been daiscussed in the OP's Q comments section :)