# dynamic checkbox with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I want to create a form with dynamic check box, when a user click the button the form will add the same form next after the previous form. I have tried a lot but didn't get it, also i tried with clone method, i get the form every time when I click the button but it was not clickable. Can anyone help?

Here is my JS below

```
$('#check-type').click(function(){
    $('.multiple-choice').show();
    var sth = $('.multiple-choice:first').clone().appendTo('.container');
    $('.multiple-choice:last').hide();
});
```

and my HTML

```
<button id="check-type" value="Multiple choice">Multiple choice</button>
<div class="container"></div>
<form class="multiple-choice">
    <div id="choice" class="css-selectbox">
        <h3 id="title" name="question-title" class="first-header">Choice</h3>
        <p class="label-checkboxitem">Which features did you like?</p>            
        <input id="check1" onclick=uncheck(this) type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" class="input-checkboxitem">  
        <label for="check1">Materials</label>
        <br> <br> 
        <input id="check2" onclick=uncheck(this) type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" class="input-checkboxitem">  
        <label for="check2">Exam Method</label>
        <br><br>             
        <input id="check6" onclick=uncheck(this) type="checkbox" name="check" value="check6" class="input-checkboxitem">
        <label for="check6">None</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: After form is cloned, element's ids will not be unique anymore - it can cause problems

Comment: What is wrong there: http://jsfiddle.net/dKxqa/?

Comment: Don't use inline event handlers (like `onclick` etc) when you have something like jQuery on your page. This goes against everything jQuery stands for. jQuery gives you advanced ways to define event handlers, use them instead.

Comment: @Regent i dont think it is working properly. Can you check that jsfiddle again?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are hiding the `last` element?

Simply commenting that line got the code running for me.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JPtA5/)

Comment: It actually works and without commenting out this line

Comment: Yeah, it works, but I guess OP wanted to  see the result on his page.

Comment: It will be very strange to hide form wanting to show it. Even though the question is not the clearest one, I still assume that problem is in "but it was not clickable".

Comment: .multiple-choice{
  display:none;
 }

after reloading the page i wanted to hide the form except the button so i hide that last element so that it won't appear 2 forms at one click

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the following code

```
$('#check-type').click(function () {
    $("#choice").clone().prependTo(".multiple-choice");
});
```

You can also check the code at 
http://jsfiddle.net/Y538U/

Comment: checkbox is not working properly. When you click one item and add another form then u will see that form is checked automatically.

Comment: still there is a same problem.

Comment: @raj so your problem was that there are some (same as in original one) checked boxes in dynamically created form? It definitely was not mentioned in question.

Comment: @Regent what i mean is the first form is clickable but when you add another form and click on the check boxes it doesn't work instead it affects on the first form. you can check in the jsfiddle above by Usman Khawaja where there is still a problem

Comment: @UsmanKhawaja there is some change in the code but still i can see the problem there.

Comment: @raj in [Usman Khawaja's updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y538U/6/) (I just add `alert` on clicking) I click on checkbox of another form, check box becomes checked, it doesn't affect first form and its ID is alerted without problems. But if you check whether check box is checked or not using `input` ID, than you should understand that you have multiple `input`'s with same ID (which is bad idea, by the way), so it's not obvious which `input`'s state you will get.

Comment: @Regent thanks, i got the point what you mean and just a question, is it possible to have multiple input with different id by clone() method?

Comment: @raj `.clone()` can't do it for you. So you should either switch from `id` to something else (`class` or `data-id` for example) or modify IDs after cloning: [example of changing IDs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126395/how-to-jquery-clone-and-change-id)