# Clearing text field using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and I have only one row in it. I am generating rows dynamically when the Enter button is pressed. This is my code.

```
   <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Amount</th>
                <th class="text-center">Installment</th>
                <th class="text-center">Source of Money</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row1" id="rw1">
                <td class="text-center" id="rw1cl1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" id="rw1cl2">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" id="rw1cl3">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="sm">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#sm').on('keyup', function(e) {

                    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                    if (code == 13) {
                        var cloned = $('.row1').first().clone(true);
                        cloned.insertAfter("#rw1");

                    }

                });

            });


        </script>
```

I am getting cloned rows as I expected. But the problem is I am getting cloned divs with the texts which were already inserted to previous row which were used to make the clone.

Since I am new to JQuery although I am bit familiar with JavaScript, I cannot figure out how to do it. I tried several stackoverflow answers, but I ended up with no luck.

Please Help me to solve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Try `var cloned = $('.row1').first().clone();`

Comment: You are also cloning the `#ID`.. not good at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clearing textboxes on clone:

```
 var cloned = $('.row1').first().clone(true);
 cloned.find('input').val("");
```

**Update:** as gmo suggested, you should not clone ids. ids should be unique. You should assign new id to cloned TR element.

```
 var cloned = $('.row1').first().clone(true);
 cloned.attr('id','rw'+($('tbody tr').length+1))
 cloned.find('input').val("");
```

Comment: As this is the accepted answer, I suggest (for better practice) provide a modification to OP script to avoid cloning the `id attr`. Something like this for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126395/how-to-jquery-clone-and-change-id or add a note warning about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cloned = $('.row1').first().clone(true);
cloned.insertAfter("#rw1").find("input").val("");//instering clone after #rw1 and clearing input fields
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/beqmsknv/15/)

Comment: Answering with code is fine, but an explanation of what you're doing could go a long way for others reading this...

Answer (score 0):

The boolean argument in `.clone()` determines whether or not to copy the elements data and events. Try `var cloned = $('.row1').first().clone();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#sm').on('keyup', function(e) {

                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if (code == 13) {
                    var cloned = $('.row1').first().clone(true);
                    cloned.find("input").val("").end().insertAfter("#rw1");

                }

            });

        });


    </script>
```