# Generate spans with ids using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have the following code which creates new spans with some input fields:

```
function add_course() {
     var newspan = document.createElement('span');
     newspan.innerHTML = 'Degree: <input type="text" name = "degree[]"> Course: <input type="text" name = "course[]">';
     document.getElementById('degree_course').appendChild(newspan); 
}

function add_skill() {
     var newspan = document.createElement('span');
     newspan.innerHTML = 'Skill: <input type="text" name = "skill[]"> Level: <input type="number"min ="1" max = "5" name = "level[]">';
     document.getElementById('skills').appendChild(newspan); 
}
```

I would like those spans to have a different id each. For example, in the case of add_course, if 3 spans where generated, i'd like them to have an id like: course_1, course_2, course_3 (skill_1, skill_2, skill_3 in the skills case).

I know I'll have to put and id="course_VAR" in the innerHTML and create a var that i'll inscrease everytime. (There won't be a *for* cicle, because the function will trigger when I hit a specific button).

```
<input class="buttons" type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_course();" value="Add Course" />
```

My question is, how can I get the var in the id and make it increase without a *for* cycle?

Comment: Just use a global variable (or one that's accessible from both functions) and increment it each time one of the functions is called.

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126395/how-to-jquery-clone-and-change-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do it add a counter, then use `setAttribute`

```
var counter = 0;

function add_course() {
    var newspan = document.createElement('span');
    newspan.setAttribute('id', "course_"+counter);
    newspan.innerHTML = 'Degree: <input type="text" name = "degree[]"> Course: <input type="text" name = "course[]">';
    document.getElementById('degree_course').appendChild(newspan);
    counter += 1;
}
```

Comment: @ipg24 If this helped you, you can click the checkmark next to my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Put your var outside of function scope and increment it inside.

```
var idCounter = 0;

function add_course() {
  var newspan = document.createElement('span');
  newspan.id = 'course_' + idCounter++;
  newspan.innerHTML = 'Degree: <input type="text" name = "degree[]"> Course: <input type="text" name = "course[]">';
  document.getElementById('degree_course').appendChild(newspan)
}
```

Comment: That will add id's to the inputs inside the span... Is there a way to make the span itself have the id? Thanks :)

Comment: @ipg24 added my answer, which does that exactly :)

Comment: @ipg24 Now span itself has an id.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently wrong with using a global or outer-scope variable to track this, as suggested in some of the other answers. But as an alternative, if you like to keep things 'tidy', you can do this:

```
var getIdFactory = function(pref) {
    return {
        counter: 0,
        prefix: pref,
        next: function() {
          this.counter++;
          return this.prefix+'_'+this.counter;
        }
    }
}

var courseId = getIdFactory('course');
var skillId = getIdFactory('skill');
```

Then, any time you need a new div ID, call (for instance) `courseId.next()`.

```
function add_course() {
    var newspan = document.createElement('span');
    newspan.innerHTML = 'Degree: <input type="text" name = "degree[]"> Course: <input type="text" name = "course[]">';
    newspan.setAttribute('id', courseId.next());
    document.getElementById('degree_course').appendChild(newspan);
}
```

In your example here, this might be overkill. But one of the advantages here is that your id generation logic can be as complicated as you need, because it's self-contained.

JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2anpoLty/3/).