# Cloning a html tag id element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to clone a element with id `abc` to `abc1,abc2,abc3` etc when I click the element with `abc` id.

Here is the code I am trying which isn't working :(

```html
<html><body>
 <p onclick="aa()" id="abc">HEEYYEYEY</p>
 <p id="xx"></p>
</body>
<script>
var temp=0;
function aa(){
 temp=temp+1;
 document.getElementById("xx").innerHTML=temp;
 $('#abc').clone().appendTo('#abc'+temp);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Please help. What am I doing wrong?
And is there any way so that I can place these cloned elements to somewhere specific I want (say below some image or after a paragraph with id `pr`)

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE**: question updated (class="abc has been changed to id="abc")(still not working)

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/clone/ "Note: Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate `id` attributes". you need to clone into a new variable, change the id of the element in that new variable, then insert it into the dom. e.g. `foo = el.clone(); foo.id = 'new unique id'; foo.appendTo(...);`

Comment: You have no `id=abc` in html shown ... or `id=abc1,abc2 etc`. A proper explanation of what you are expecting this code to do would help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to JQuery clone() and change id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126395/how-to-jquery-clone-and-change-id)

Comment: you use `$('#abc')` and there is no element with ID `abc`, only with `class` `abc`

Comment: Also you're using a jQuery-function without even including jQuery.

Comment: You append your new element to abc1 in the first iteration but your id is just abc

Comment: Explain what expected results are. it is still not clear what you are wanting to do. The target elements you are trying to append to don't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you clone, set your attribute `id` to whatever you want it to. then append to the `#xx` div like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
 $('#abc').on('click', function() {
        count++;
     var newItem = $(this).clone().attr('id', 'abc' + count);
        $('#xx').append(newItem);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="abc">HEEYYEYEY</p>
<p id="xx"></p>
```

ps. youre using both vanilla javascript and jquery at the same time. it would be easier to maintain and read if you stuck to one

Answer (score 0):

You append the element to `#abc0` (and so on) but there are no elements with those ids. Try to append your elements to the body.

Comment: This is not an full answer to this question

Comment: Yes, this is an answer to the question. It deserves staying there. Even though there might be *other* problems, this is a fair attempt at helping the problem.