# Duplicate Div With New ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a function that duplicates a div and increases the new div's `id` by 1

```
function duplicate(){
    // Get content to clone
    var line_to_clone = $('#fields_1').html();
    // Get new line id
    var next_line_id = $('.items').length + 1;
    // Add the div container
    var line_to_clone = '<div id="fields_' + next_line_id + '" class="items">' + line_to_clone + '</div>';
    // Create new line
    var new_line = line_to_clone.replace(/_1/gi, "_" + next_line_id);
    // Render it
    $('#renderer').append(new_line);
}
```

It will work but the ids are wrong when it hits 10

```
<div id="fields_8" class="items">
<div id="fields_9" class="items">
<div id="fields_100" class="items">
<div id="fields_111" class="items">
<div id="fields_122" class="items">
<div id="fields_133" class="items">
<div id="fields_144" class="items">
```

Comment: try to replace your code `var next_line_id = $('.items').length + 1;` with this 
'var next_line_id = parseInt($('.items').length) + 1;`

Comment: do this `var next_line_id = parseInt( $('.items').length + 1);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to JQuery clone() and change id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126395/how-to-jquery-clone-and-change-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can make use of jQuery **[`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)** function, also getting the `id` of the last item using jQuery **[`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)** selector then increase it by one before appending the html of the new item, like this:

**[jsFiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/jme14Lh3/1/)**

```js
$('#btn-foo').on('click', function() {
  var lastItem = $('#renderer .items:last'),
    lastID = parseInt(lastItem.attr('id').replace('fields_', ''));
  $('#renderer').append(lastItem.clone().attr('id', "fields_" + (lastID + 1)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-foo">Add</button>
<hr>
<div id="renderer">
  <div id="fields_1" class="items"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Updated:**

Upon a comment from the OP, there're issues of duplicating the values of input fields, also the values of `id` and `name` attributes must be unique, therefore, in this [**jsFiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/jme14Lh3/6/) we have them all fixed

Comment: Thank you i ended up using your solution.

Comment: Is there a way to clear input fields in the cloned div so that its blank?

Comment: Something like this:
`<div id="fields_1" class="items">
 <div class="form_div"><input id="name_1" type="text" value="" name="name_1"></div>
 <div class="form_div"><input id="lastname_1" type="text" value="" name="lastname_1"></div>
 <div class="form_div"><textarea id="comments_1" cols="80" rows="2" name="comments_1"></textarea></div>
</div>`

Comment: check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jme14Lh3/3/), it should clear the value in input fields I believe, but you still have other issues, about `name` and `id` values, those can't be repeated and should be unique

Comment: this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jme14Lh3/6/) fixes the issues of having unique `name` and `id` attributes, as well as resetting the values of the input fields

Answer (score 1):

Please check below snippet.

```js
function duplicate(){
// Get content to clone
var line_to_clone = $('#fields_1').html();
// Get new line id
var next_line_id = $('.items').length + 1;
  
// Add the div container
var line_to_clone = '<div id="fields_' + next_line_id + '" class="items">' + line_to_clone + '</div>';
// Create new line

// Render it
$('#renderer').append(line_to_clone);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="renderer">
  <div id="fields_1" class="items">123</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="duplicate()"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this it works too but i ended up using .clone because i added a remove button too.

Comment: That's not fare, fist accepted my answer and then removed it

Comment: Sorry about that mate as i said yours works too but the second solution is better for my issue. Voted up

Comment: No issues. Great to see you find my solution helpful atleast.