# I want to increment multiple div from existing div along with css using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a one div with `id="div"`.

I need to replicate my div three times with new divs having:

```
id="div1"
id="div2"
id="div3"
```

I want to append div inside the body element as shown in this image.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $('body').append('#div1' + i + '');
  }
});
```

```css
#div1{
  width: 167px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using the clone property of jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var a=$('body');
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            a.append($("#div1").clone());
            
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id="div1">sdfs</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: This will generate 4 `div`s with the same `id`.

Comment: it is just an example of what he can do

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('commonClass')[0].outerHTML
for(var i =0;i<3;i++){
$('body').append(elem)

}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/kuon64pp/3/)

Note: This is just demo. Please adjust css accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/), [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [`appendTo()`](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) methods.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
    $('#div1')
      // clone the element
      .clone()
      // update id attribute of the element
      .attr('id', 'div' + i)
      // append to the body
      .appendTo('body')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" style="width: 167px;height: 30px; background-color: #ff0000;">div</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys all ur support. i got what i expected.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var div = $("div[id^=div]:last");

for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  var newDivId = parseInt($(div).attr("id").match(/\d+/g), 10) + i;
  var newDiv = div.clone().attr('id', 'div' + newDivId);
  $('body').append(newDiv);
}
```

```css
div[id^="div"] {
  width: 167px; height: 30px; background-color: #ff0000; margin:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div1'>
  Lorum Ipsum
</div>
```

Credits: [Roko's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126395/how-to-jquery-clone-and-change-id)

Answer (score 0):

Create div to append elements

```
<div id="divbox"></div>
```

CSS for div

```
.dclass {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background:red;
  margin:10px;
}
```

Generate div and add html to other div

```
var container="";
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  container += '<div id="div'+ i + '" class="dclass">'+ i + '</div>';
}
$('#divbox').html(container);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/komal2887/3o96Lzdy/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var div = $('#div1');
   for (i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
     div = div.clone();
     div.attr('id', i);
     $('body').prepend(div);
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" style="width: 167px;margin:15px;height: 30px; background-color: #ff0000;">div

</div>
```