# default value not displaying in new dynamic created row input field in php

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic, clone

I'm working on a small HTML form integrated with a table. The table has an input field named "name" which have  value from some variable $name and   with other two input field (city and country) without any  value.

This works well for the first row. However, when I dynamically add more rows, the new input fields don't display the   value $name in new dynamic created row field. Here's my current code setup:

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="table-success" style="background-color: #3fbbc0;">
        <tr>                       
            <th width="15%"><center>Name</th>
            <th width="15%"><center>city</th>
            <th width="15%"><center>country</th>
            <th width="5%"></th>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="BtnAdd()">Add Item</button>                         
            </th>
        </tr>  
    </thead>    
    <tbody id="TBody">                  
   
        <tr id="TRow" class="d-none">
            <td>    
                <input type="text"  name="name[]" id="name" value = "<?php echo $name; ?>">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"  name="city[]" id="city" >
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"  name="country[]" id="country" >
            </td>
            <td class="NoPrint">
                <button type="button" onclick="BtnDel(this)">x</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script to add deynamic rows in table

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function GetPrint()
{
    /*For Print*/
    window.print();
}

function BtnAdd()
{
    /*Add Button*/
    var v = $("#TRow").clone().appendTo("#TBody") ;
    $(v).find("input").val('');
    $(v).find("input").autocomplete({
        source: 'backend-script.php'  
    });
    $(v).removeClass("d-none");
    $(v).find("th").first().html($('#TBody tr').length - 1);
}

function BtnDel(v)
{
    /*Delete Button*/
    $(v).parent().parent().remove(); 
    GetTotal();

    $("#TBody").find("tr").each(
        function(index) {
           $(this).find("th").first().html(index);
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

Comment: SO where is the `<form>`

Comment: Won't you end up with duplicate ids/invalid html when you duplicate that table row?

Comment: You are duplicating fields with the same id? `id="name"` ID's  should be unique

Comment: Javascript does no have access to `<?php echo $name; ?>` once you have finished the PHP process on the server

Comment: @RiggsFolly can u guide with example sir if possible for u

Comment: Umar, just remove this line `$(v).find("input").val('');` you have commanded to blank that (and the other fields). The computer is only that clever as the person programming it, only different for those rich kids that run the AI shop but they don't share the code with you.

Comment: And about what was commented about the ID: It should be unique, and you don't have it unique, but it's also HTML and old, stable browser tech, so not this issue. If you're looking for related Q&A, check this one: [How to clone and change id?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10126395/367456)